# How to sync a number between multiple google cloud instances using google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to sync an operation between multiple instances in google cloud.

In the home folder of an image from where I create new instances, I have several files that are named like this: `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`,... `50000.txt`.

I have another file in the google cloud storage bucket named `gs://bucket/current_file.txt` that contains a number in a single line which indicates the latest file that is being processed by all the running the google cloud instances. Initially this file looks like this:

```
0
```

Now I am creating multiple google instances one by one. The instances have a startup script like this:

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket/current_file.txt /home/ubuntu/;
past_file=`tail /home/ubuntu/current_file.txt`;
current_file=$((past_file+1));
echo $current_file > /home/ubuntu/current_file.txt;
gsutil cp /home/ubuntu/current_file.txt gs://bucket/;
process.py /home.ubuntu/$current_file.txt;
```

So this script downloads the value of the current file that is being processed by another instance, then it increments it by 1, and starts processing the incremented file. Also `gs://bucket/current_file.txt` is updated so that other instances know the name of the next file they can start processing. When I have only 1 instance running, the `gs://bucket/current_file.txt` is updated properly, but when I am running multiple instances, sometimes the value in `gs://bucket/current_file.txt` goes up to a value and then erratically it falls back to a decreased value.

My assumption is somehow two different instances are trying to upload the same file at the same time and messes up the integer value inside the text file.

Is it anyway possible to lock the file so that other instances wait before one instance can overwrite the `gs://bucket/currrent_file.txt`?

If not, can someone suggest any other mechanism through which I can update the current_file number once it is being processed by one instance, and then can be communicated to other instances so that they can start processing the following files when they complete processing a file at hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. In your architecture, you need some mechanism to lock your `current-file` counter so that only one process at a time is able to change its value. You want to be able to apply a mutex or lock to the file, when one process opens it to increment it, so that another process is unable to increment it concurrently.

I recommend you consider alternative approaches.

Even if you are able to lock the counter, your "workers" will block, waiting their turn to increment this variable when they should be able to continue processing files. You also limit processing to one file at a time when, it may be more efficient for your processes to grab batches of files at a time.

There are various approaches for you to consider.

If your set of files is predetermined, i.e. you always have 50k. When you start, you could decide how many workers you wish to use and then give each of them part of the problem to solve. If you chose 1000 workers, the first may be assigned 1.txt..50.txt, the 2nd 51.txt..99.txt etc. If there are gaps in the files, the worker would skip the missing file.

In a more complex scenario, when the files are created in the bucket randomly and ongoing, a common practice is to queue the processing. Have a look at [Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/) and [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview). In this approach, you track files as they arrive. For each file you enqueue a job to process it. With both Tasks Queues and Pub/Sub you can create push or pull queues.

In either approach, you would write a worker that accepts jobs (files) from the queue, processes them and does something with the processed file. This approach has 2 advantages over the simpler case: The first is that you can dynamically increase|reduce the number of workers based on the queue depth (number of files to be processed). The second is that, if a worker fails, it won't take the job from the queue and so another worker can replace it and complete the file processing.

You could move processed files to a "processed" bucket to track completion. This way, if your job fails, you need only restart with the files that have not yet been processed.

Lastly, rather than creating instances one-by-one, have a look at auto-scaling using [Managed Instance Groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) or perhaps consider using Kubernetes. Both these technologies help you clone many similar processes from a single template. While neither of these solutions solves your coordination problem, either would help you manage all the workers.

Comment: @Syed Areniful haque I agree Cloud Pub/Sub seems the most robust and the best way to use a Task queue approach. You might also consider using [concurrency control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/ObjectVersioningandConcurrencyControl#concurrency-control) for GCS with versioning.